# AngularJS: Best practices for routes and controllers

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-ng-route, angular-controller

on our company, we're currently working on a single page web application. Users can login and fill their profiles with data and share those with other subscribers (it's a social network-ish application).
Now, I've imagined this schema:

- the users data are provided by a UserService, using REST APIs to recover profiles information;
- the profiles related pages are managed by a unique controller (ProfileController);

my question is: what's the best way to associate a route (let's say "view-profile") to a specific controller method (ProfileController.viewProfile)? Is this a right pattern in AngularJS?

Thanks!

Comment: Specify the `controller` property in the route config?

Comment: @tymeJV So, in the stateProvider configuration, instead of having
controller: ProfileController
I can specify controller:ProfileController. _someMethod()_, is it what you mean?

Comment: Ohh- controller *method* - missed that last part... you can't really bind a view to just a specific method...

Comment: @tymeJV You're right, but as explained in the link in my answer below it's possible to achieve the same result using `resolve` in the state configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigating further I've found that the best way to achieve the result I want is by using the resolve in the state configuration, as explained in this article: https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-skinny-angularjs-controllers.

EDIT:
I'll try to explain it a little bit. What I'm trying to achieve is to route a specific application state to a controller *method*, in order to avoid preloading a huge subset of data everytime I access the controller. Let's say I've this situation in my ui-router

```
.state('view-profile', {
   url: '/view-profile',
   templateUrl: 'components/profile/profile.html',
   controller: 'ProfileController'
})
[...]
.state('edit-profile', {
   url: '/edit-profile',
   templateUrl: 'components/profile/edit-profile.html',
   controller: 'ProfileController'   
})
```

Since the ProfileController could potentially do a lot of stuff, not necessary related to edit/view, I'd like to set a specific controller method to be called when I navigate to these urls.
In other MVC frameworks you can associate a route to a specific controller method, so you'll have

```
route: /edit-profile -> resolvesAs: ProfileController.editProfile(args)
```

Unfortunately, there's no really a way to do this in AngularJS 1.4, at least not using the ui-router.
But fortunately enough, we can use the `resolve` attribute on the ui-router configuration to avoid preloading useless data for a specific route.

Comment: It looks like you're not using the standard ngRoute, but I think even the other libraries have the resolve property, because I think the route itself is the same object. This will call a method and pass the result into the Controller as a constructor param. Note that if your controller is doing things not related to the View, it's not a great separation of concerns.